# Upgrade to Disco Dingo Fails

Tags: apt, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I've tried a whole lot of stuff that I found on the Interwebs and I may have made things worse. Here is my current situation:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.178ubuntu9.1) ...
Cannot open display ":0"
bin/setupcon: 897: bin/setupcon: /$installdir/bin/ckbcomp: not found
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 installed keyboard-configuration package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu9.1); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu9.1); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
Preparing to unpack .../keyboard-configuration_1.178ubuntu12_all.deb ...
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.178ubuntu12); however:
Removing xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu (18.1.0-1) ...
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-mini is not configured yet.
Setting up xfce4-screenshooter (1.9.5-1) ...
Setting up xfce4-terminal (0.8.7.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xfburn (0.5.5-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-fsguard-plugin (1.1.0-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin (0.5.0-1) ...
Setting up xfce4-netload-plugin (1.3.1-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-mount-plugin (1.1.3-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-systemload-plugin (1:1.2.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90:amd64 (1:11.0.3-2) ...
Setting up gnome-keyring (3.31.91-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ...
Setting up libthunarx-3-0:amd64 (1.8.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xfce4-notes-plugin (1.8.1-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-mailwatch-plugin (1.2.0-3) ...
Setting up xfdesktop4 (4.13.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up thunar (1.8.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xfce4-places-plugin (1.7.0-4) ...
Setting up xfce4-cpugraph-plugin (1.0.5-2) ...
Setting up thunar-media-tags-plugin (0.3.0-2) ...
Setting up xfce4 (4.12.5) ...
Setting up thunar-volman (0.9.1-1) ...
Setting up thunar-archive-plugin (0.4.0-2) ...
Setting up xfce4-goodies (4.12.6) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.29) ...
Setting up python-docutils (0.14+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up python-sphinx (1.8.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-docutils (0.14+dfsg-4) ...
Setting up python3-botocore (1.12.71+repack-1) ...
Setting up awscli (1.16.81-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu19) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-17-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs
    integration and avoid this warning.
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.12-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.38.1+dfsg-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup
 kbd
 console-setup-linux
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I futzed around for a long time over the next few days and the problem has gone away. No idea why. Sure would like an explanation on how to deal with issues with these packages because the problem keeps coming up when I upgrade Ubuntu:

```
keyboard-configuration
console-setup
kbd
console-setup-linux
```

Answer (score 0):

these problem is on me too.
it a bug between awk and libreadline.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/readline_bak
sudo mv /usr/lib/libreadline* /usr/lib/readline_bak
sudo apt install -f
```